# Parallel build in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs

I am testing vNext in TFS 2015. I have not found a way to trigger builds in parallel. Is that not supported in TFS?

I have found this:

http://www.jaylee.org/post/2013/03/30/Building-in-Parallel-Across-Multiple-Build-Agents-with-TFS-2012-with-Gated-Checkin.aspx

but that is old and not compatible with vNext.

To be clear I would like to be able to trigger the same build def multiple times, running each (including all its build steps) concurrently.

Comment: Well, let's be clear: Are you talking about running multiple **builds** in parallel, or running **build steps** in parallel, within a single build?

Comment: @u123 Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no equivalent of a drag and drop parallel task. However you can spin up as many build processes as you like using PowerShell. Each of the built in tasks are just PowerShell commands and PowerShell also supports workflow tasks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a parallel tickbox under the options tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned 
[Build Options:MultiConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/define/options) here and 
[Build Define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build) here

TFS2015 vNext may be only support parallel  build for different platforms by different build variables