# TFS 2015 v.Next build: Parallel solution builds?

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015

In TFS v.Next build there is a possibility for parallel builds. However, I think it only works to build multiple `configurations` / `platforms` in parallel. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116348/parallel-build-in-tfs-2015))

You can specify multiple projects/solutions to build in the Projects field of the `Visual Studio Build` or the `MSBuild` build tasks.

Is there a way to build these multiple solutions in parallel to save some time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Multi-configuration is used to Build multiple configurations with the same steps, not multiple solutions. If you use Release, you may have multiple environments to achieve multiple solutions in parallel.

But for Build, no such option by default, you may submit a User Voice at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Oh, and TeamServices UserVoice is probably more appropriate:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services