# Specify the maximum number of concurrent builds on TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-system

As per TFS documentation ([Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers)), when the "Batch changes" option is selected, the maximum number of concurrent builds can also be specified, but I can not find any documentation on how to limit the maximum number of concurrent builds. Any help, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You make a statement about what the documentation says, then say that you can't find any documentation on the subject.

Comment: @DanielMann In TFS docs it's said that when you activate the Batch Changes option, you can specify the number of concurrent builds per branch, but they don't say how or where we can specify that. We have activated this option, but we don't know how to limit the number of concurrent builds per branch. We have searched around the documentation and the internet with no results. I was asking if someone knows how to accomplish that: specifying the maximum number of concurrent builds per branch.

Comment: How many build agents do your team have in  your agent pool?

Answer (score 0):

First just as the doc said, the **batch changes** is used for reducing the number of builds you are running.

> If you select this option, when a build is running, the system waits
>   until the build is completed and then queues another build of all
>   changes that have not yet been built.

However you can't run multiple solution builds in parallel in TFS 2015, it's only able to  run multiple configurations and platforms in parallel. Some related topic:

- [Parallel build in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116348/parallel-build-in-tfs-2015)
- [TFS 2015 v.Next build: Parallel solution builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464214/tfs-2015-v-next-build-parallel-solution-builds)

So the concurrent builds should be running builds on multiple build agents the same time. You can't run concurrent builds on a single agent. It looks like a lack of content, I will submit this through internal channels, once updated will let you know. You could also submit a feedback on [MS connect page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) or [GITHub Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues) page. Through this you may get a faster response.