# Does MSBUILD run on ARM-CPUs?

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, arm

we are planning to use a TFS / MSBUILD on a ARM CPU.
Now we haven't found any information, if that could actually work.

Has anyone ever tried to compile using an ARM CPU?
We want to use a ARM-CPU based server as build server for C#.

Comment: Have you installed Windows on your server yet?

Comment: Nice question. Are you looking for Windows 10 or a Raspbian solution? (In both cases I suspect it is bleeding edge requiring a pile of beta software)

Comment: The essence of the Question was that we are thinking of using an ARM based Server as Buildserver. Cause you can have a whole lot of cores for parallel building.

Comment: Could you installed a windows sever system on your ARM-CPU based server successfully?

Comment: I was kinda looking for a Windows 10 IoT solution or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vNext build with TFS2015 and later, parallel build is **not support** for now.
Details you can refer this question: [Parallel build in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116348/parallel-build-in-tfs-2015)

And there has been a feature request in uservoice site:

> *User Voice:*
>
> [Ability to build multiple solutions in parallel using vNext Build](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14257521-ability-to-build-multiple-solutions-in-parallel-us)

With XAML build you could achieve through this way:[Building in Parallel Across Multiple Build Agents in TFS2012 for Metro Apps](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2013/03/30/Building-in-Parallel-Across-Multiple-Build-Agents-with-TFS-2012-with-Gated-Checkin.aspx)

---

As for if the build can run on arm based CPU, when you run the build with TFS. You need to have **Team Foundation Build Service** which has the same [operating system requirements as TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-cn/docs/setup-admin/requirements). **Hardware** requirements for the build service are the same as the **operating system** on which it is running.  *Source Link:* [System requirements for Team Foundation Build Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578619.aspx)

So if you could not installed a windows sever system which supported above on your ARM-CPU based server, then you could also not be able to run the TFS build.